# Angular DI providers vs viewProviders

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am trying to understand Angular's DI framework and referring to the official docs in https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection; particularly the **difference between  viewProviders and providers** attributes.

While I can't say that the content is easy to follow (especially the section where it explains how it works under the hood using the combined logical tree and using the notations `@Provide` and `@Inject` sometimes in `<#VIEW>` and sometimes in the selector tag of the component), I concluded that using viewProviders instead of providers can affect the rendering of a projected content using `<ng-content>`

Coming to the question, I don't see an explanation to a scenario if the **same DI token is used both in providers and viewProviders**.

Eg.

Referring to the snippet from parent.component.ts, my question is : **If by virtue of un-commenting the providers attribute enables rendering the value "world" as configured in the element injector, instead of the value "hello" in module injector, why is it disregarding the value "angular"?**

```
viewProviders: [{ provide: Service, useValue: { value: 'world' } }],
  // providers: [{ provide: Service , useValue: { value: 'angular' } }], // If I uncomment this line the "hello" changes to "world" and the value "angular" is disregarded
```

in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-syh4mx

*It's probably not a valid use case but I'm interested to understand why it behaves the way it does.*

Answer (score 1):

Basing on this [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/79742a397fc60c6d2499d64736bbc476a7e3e6c9/aio/content/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.md#providers-vs-viewproviders) you are getting value injected to the closest injector. If you have commented out providers the closes injector is global injector and if its uncommented closest injector is on component.

It kind of looks like a bug because global injector by intuition also is less important than `viewProvider` and when `provider` is not present it should behave similarly. But it its intended behavior as you can see in [unit test](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ab3f4c9fe143d650b4a1e521d544e0fd4811f995/packages/core/test/render3/providers_spec.ts#L298) which defines how it behaves when having both `providers` and `viewProviders` defined. And you can find the exact answer to your question at the end of this [section](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/79742a397fc60c6d2499d64736bbc476a7e3e6c9/aio/content/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.md#using-the-providers-array)

> ```
> <app-root @NgModule(AppModule)
>         @Inject(FlowerService) flower=>"">
>   <#VIEW>
>     <p>Emoji from FlowerService: {{flower.emoji}} ()</p>
>     <app-child @Provide(FlowerService="")
>                @Inject(FlowerService)=>""> <!-- search ends here -->
>       <#VIEW> <!-- search starts here -->
>         <h2>Parent Component</h2>
>         <p>Emoji from FlowerService: {{flower.emoji}} ()</p>
>       </#VIEW>
>      </app-child>   </#VIEW> </app-root>
> ```
>
> When  requests the FlowerService, the injector begins its
>   search at the <#VIEW> belonging to  (<#VIEW> is included
>   because it is injected from @Component()) and ends with .

**<#VIEW> is included because it is injected from @Component()** so like if `providers` are part of annotation then its triggers including view as part of lookup list and having a view on lookup list checks value in `viewProviders` first.

You can find code related to this behavior [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d1ea1f4c7f3358b730b0d94e65b00bc28cae279c/packages/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/annotations/src/component.ts#L214)

Comment: Thank you for your research. May I ask, how did you infer "if providers are part of annotation then its triggers including view as part of lookup list". Is it based on your understanding of the code? The documentation doesn't say that explicitly.

Comment: Also, when you say "and having a view on lookup list checks value in viewProviders first", how would you explain the behavior if I modify the snippet as below  `viewProviders: [{ provide: Service }],  providers: [{ provide: Service , useValue: { value: 'angular' } }],`  By the same logic, shouldn't it pick "angular"? When I tried in stackblitz, service is undefined and the html output is  **projection:**

Comment: Furthermore, if I modify as below:  `//viewProviders: [{ provide: Service }],  
providers: [{ provide: Service , useValue: { value: 'angular' } }],`  the output is  **angular  projection:  angular**  which makes sense but I would have expected the same output for the previous scenario as well

Comment: 1. I get this mostly from that documentation parts I have linked a little bit from code. It actually hard to infer that from code as there is a lot of relations between annotation decorators used on components. I couldn't find exact place where that particular behavior is handled. But from code I see that rendering logic asks for dependencies declared on metadata provided via annotations.
That bolded sentence is what triggered in my mind why it works as it works.

Comment: 2 and 3. if you write `viewProviders: [{ provide: Service }]` it is undefined because you declared Service as undefined you would have to write either of those to have it declared as:
`viewProviders: [Service]` or `viewProviders: [{ provide: Service, useClass: Service }]`

Comment: I understand the difference between `viewProviders:[Service]` and `viewProviders:[{provide:Service}]`. I kept it purposefully because my expectation is that when it does not find the `value` from the `viewProviders`, it should look into the `providers` which is defined as `[{ provide: Service , useValue: { value: 'angular' } }]` but it did not. You could argue that `providers` has no significance if `viewProviders` is also present which brings us back to the original question.

Comment: To summarize, based on your comment, if both of them are present, `providers` does not contribute in configuring the injector with the DI token but simply activates the `viewProviders` to do so. In the risk of repeating myself, I must say I can't infer that from the documentation link. I'll accept your answer, though, if I don't see a better one.